# Javascript: How to get single values from a sharepoint custom list? (2013)

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list

I found several articles about how to get a single value from a sharepoint custom list, but I am new to javascript and so I cound't implement them to my situation.

**I belive what is want is quite simple:** I have a list with 2 column `Name` and `ID`. The use enter the `ID` (what is a unique value) in a new form (different from the list's new form) to a textbox and the `Name` from the same row appears in an other textbox. So:

1. User enter the `ID` to a textbox and press enter/click out/ect.
2. Based on the enterred `ID` the script search in the targeted list's `ID` column for the `ID`.
3. If the ID exist the `Name`'s value from the same row inserted to an empty textbox in the form where the user enterred the `ID` to the first textbox.

Sounds easy but even after several attempt I only got [object Obecjet], [object promises] ect. And finaly when I tought it should work I got a random text "Next Page" insted of the `Name` so probably I am doing something wrong. So I would be glad if someome who experienced would show me an example code for this situation.

I add my code too, it is not contains errors, but give me the "Next Page" instead of working well:

```
< script type = script type="text/javascript "src = ".../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
< script type = "text/javascript "src".../SiteAssets/nanoajax.min.js" > < /script>
< script type = "text/javascript "src".../SiteAssets/sharepointplus-4.0.min.js" > < /script>
< script type = "text/javascript" >
          $(function() {
            $SP().list("TargetListTitle").get({
              fields: "NameColumnTitle",
              where: 'IDColumnTitle = 101'
            }).then(function(res) {
              for (var key in res) {
                $("input[id='EmptyTextfieldID']").val(key);
              }
            });
          });
< /script>
```

Thanks you very much for your kind guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

You don't need nanoajax.min.js. jQuery is enough.

If you changed "*Title*" column's name to "*Name*", you should use *Title* instead of *Name*.

```
< script type = "text/javascript "src = ".../SiteAssets/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
< script type = "text/javascript "src".../SiteAssets/sharepointplus-4.0.min.js" > < /script>
< script type = "text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function () {

//If you know element, use #. 

$("#IDTextFieldID").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {//Detect if enter pressed

        //Query the sharepoint list
        $SP().list("TargetListTitle", "http://www.spsitecollectionaddress.com/").get(
        {
            fields: "ID,Name",
            where: 'ID = "101"'
        },
        function getData(data) {

            //Set return value to empty text box
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                $("#NameTextFieldID").val(data[i].getAttribute("Name"));
            }

        });

    }
});


});

< /script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am testing it now. It contains no errors, but no result in the targeted textbox, and even if I set an alert inside the "for" not activate so I suspect targetting problems. May I ask you: 1. If my targeted list is "http://hu-shrp-form-d.sanofi.com/sites/Registry/Lists/INNList" then what should I add to replace the "spsitecollectionaddress.com"? 2. If my ID is a number do I need to convert the input to number too or it works with the "101"? 3. The lists's name is their displayname or their name from the URL? Thank for your help and sry for the trouble.

Comment: Yeah looks like the data.length is 0, that is the reason the "for" not works, but I can't find why. I excluded the input part to make it more simple and I created a very simple test list with only text fields and the display/url names are the same + don't have any specific characters so the list targeting should be fine too. The remaining issue can be the URL or someting I don t think of. Now it is looking like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zetvtn7m/

Comment: 1 - You should provide "http://hu-shrp-form-d.sanofi.com/sites/Registry/" for the site address.
2 - I'm not sure but ID can be "101" or 101. Can you try both?
3 - List name is the display name of the list, not the name in the url.

Comment: Yeah I am testing all the way possible :) I excluded problem 2. and problem 3. I set the URL as you mentioned and I got an error:
"http://hu-shrp-form-d.sanofi.com/sites/Registry/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" Can it be permission problem? If I simply enter the same URL to my browser my SP home page appear with no problem, so quite strange, but I am new to both SP and JS so I may not noticing something trivial, but important.

Comment: Nope, it is not a permission problem. You should type http:// too. And be sure that there is no " " blank character at the end of the url. Also be sure that there is no blank character at the name of your list. SharePointPlus hates spaces :)

Comment: Also I've just seen your code. If you rename default title column of SharePoint list, Use "Title" instead of "Nev".

Comment: Yeah I noticed, SP hate space. Also my contry have some specific characters like "á" or "ű" so I try to avoid useing them. Quite funny when I am constructing a site for only native language speaker users xD. So I am using http:// (I got much more error when didn't) and no space, no special characters ect, but still have that error. I tryed to dig in about this "_vti_bin/Lists.asm‌​x" there are serveral articles about it, but most of them related to SPServices problems what I don't even use now or like you mentioned " " problems. So I am confused a bit, what can it be in my case.

Comment: I added new columns called "Nev" and "Szam". I don't use for anything the column named "Title" by default. And thank you for still helping me I am very grateful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66536/discussion-between-newbie-and-nefri).

Comment: If I try to run the same script in explorer (my default is chrome) I get a diferent error called: "XMLHttpRequest: 0x80070005 access denied". The related articles are about cross site scripting, but in my case both page is under the same SP site : /

Comment: I looked into it deeper. After I removed the "where" and the target textbox part of the script I could acces the list, but all the items I recive were nulls. The numbers of nulls are reflecting the numbers of items in the columns. But even If I change the field names into random texts, I don t get any error message just getting nulls. So I think I can acces the list, but I can't acces the columns of it. I tryed to add views too, but same result. I opened a new topic about it, but looks like there aren't too many experienced users of sharepointplus to figure out the problem.

Comment: [The reference:](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) of sharepointplus I use. And the new topic I [opened](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227098/javascript-trying-to-acces-values-in-a-sp-list-but-returning-only-nulls-2013#227098) Now I am suspecting server side problems, but I am not sure that can be even possible or not :P

Comment: Ohh it is solved. Looks like the field names are not the display names even if I didn't change them, so I have to use the names from the: open column settings => get URL => Field="......" part, to make it works. Annoying cause I tested this before, but that time I got other problems too, so I didn't noticed. Also not having any error with wrong adressing made it hard to find the solution. Thanks for your support again!

Comment: It's great to hear you solve your problem :)