# Sharepointplus: Trying to acces values in a SP list, but returning only nulls. (SP 2013) SOLVED

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list, sharepointplus

My goal is to read columns from the list `TestList` and write the element into an other list's new form's textbox `TestText`. But looks like even if I can acces the `TestList` the script return only with nulls. For example if the targeted column `Szam` have 4 elements then it return with 4 null if I add one more element it returns with 5 null, but I can't figure out why not contains the right values. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $SP().list("TestList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
        {
            fields: "Szam"
        },
        function getData(data)
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               console.log(data[i].getAttribute("Szam"));
               // $("#TestText").val(data[i].getAttribute("Szam"));
            }
      });
});
```

Both SP list is under the same site. I am using SP 2013, jquery.min.js and [sharepointplus-4.0.min.js.](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) The column `Szam` contains 5 element as text {1,2,3,4,5}. I as a result I can see the "null"s in the console log 5 times. In the final version I am planning to add something like `where 'Szam = "5"'` and search in other columns to get only 1 element as result and insert it to the `TestText`. I am new to both SP and JS so it can be even trivial mistakes. Thank you very much for your kind help!

Comment: Check the internal name of the field is Szam. I suspect the field name was Title which you renamed to Szam?

Comment: "Szam" is a new column, I didn't touch the "Title" column. The list contains 3 column: "Title", "Nev", "Szam". So u suspect it not accessing the right column just see that the list generaly have 5 rows?

Comment: I created this list to be very simple so all names contains no blank " "-s, no special characters and no changed titles. The internalname of the "Szam" column is: "List=%7B7632DCD3%2D4F1B%2D4F8E%2DAC8C%2DFB9C4372CD3D%7D&Field=btyn"

Comment: I am new to SharePointPlus.. not sure if you we need pass the View parameter along with fields.

Comment: I tested now an looks like even if I change the "Szam" to random characters like "Column123" or "btyn" the result is the same so it rly not finding the right column by his name :/

Comment: I am new to everything :) May I ask you to show an example for View parameter contained adressing as your suggestion? The full adress of the list is: http://.../sites/Registry/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/TestList/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Okey I figured out how to get the view ID (It was disgusting to retrive :D ). I added it to .get() before the "fields". Now looks like this: {views: "{EA3CDF07-1A28-4A44-BCB2-01F7D45A76C0}",
fields: "Szam"}. But still the same result, not even an error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using my Library :-)

First thing: the parameter is `view`, not `views` ([see documentation](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#get)).

Then, are you into the same website where you're doing the above code? If yes, no need to provide the URL.
Also try to remove the `view` and add a where clause:

```
$SP().list("TestList").get({fields:"ID,Szam", where:"ID > 0"}, function(data)   {
  console.log("len => ",data.length); // to check the number of results
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d.getAttribute("ID"),"=>",d.getAttribute("Szam"));
  })
})
```

Check the console of your browser to see the result.

Also, check the response body from the console to see what the server returned to you. It usually is a good way to see what might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your libary is very useful! In the end I figured out my problem was rly the field nameing. Sahrepoint some time create exactly the same name as the displayname and sometimes full random characters (even if I don t use any special character). (Maybe based on the field type) Someone told me I should use the displayname, but looks like I had to use the name from the URL. I checked this option before too, so I don't know why I didn't notice is that time, maybe I got other problems too when I checked it.